# Getting my phone to be an Android Device Choice

Tags: android, eclipse, lg

I have an LG G2 (LS980) from Sprint, I downloaded the driver here:
http://androidxda.com/download-lg-usb-drivers

- I've restarted both my phone and my computer.
- I have also turned on USB Debugging Mode on my phone.
- I've tried `adb kill-server` too.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why I cannot run applications from Eclipse to my phone.
This is what my Android Device Chooser window looks like:

[image]

Does anyone know what I can do?

SOLVED IT: The device asks for your permission to communicate with the computer through a pop-up that I never saw in the first place, so I had to accept the permission, so it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it, apparently the phone asks for your permission (in a pop-up, that I never first saw) to connect to the computer.  A note to other LG G2 owners.